# How to find if remote host is reachable over SSH without actually doing ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have multiple remote hosts connected to my local host (server-A).  TO ensure/filter the list of hosts which are genuinely reachable to localhost , I do ping test.

```
ping -c1 <remotehost-IP> 

if [ "$?" != "0" ];then
echo "Not reachable.Exiting..."
exit 1;
fi
```

However ping test could not provide me any check to ensure that filtered remotehost-IPs are reachable over SSH connection /port 22.

```
    non-root-user@localhost>ssh 172.26.192.15
    ssh: connect to host 172.26.192.15 port 22: Connection refused
 non-root-user@localhost>echo $?
 1

non-root-user@localhost>ssh -v  172.26.192.15
OpenSSH_3.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.26.192.15 [172.26.192.15] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.26.192.15 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 172.26.192.15 port 22: Connection refused
```

## Query:

Above check work for me if connection is refused. However, if SSH connection is possible then I enter into the remote host or proceed to password prompt. Which cause barrier to check return code.

So I wanted to know if there is any way to check if the remote IP WOULD be reachable or not reachable over SSH beforehand. ?

Comment: something like `nmap 172.26.192.0/24 -p 22`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A Bash-Specific Solution

If you are using the Bash shell specifically, then you have access to TCP and UDP sockets. For example:

```
if (exec 3<>/dev/tcp/74.207.252.238/22) 2> /dev/null; then
    echo open
else
    echo closed
fi
```

This won't tell you if the actual protocol in use is really SSH, but is often sufficient to determine that a given port is listening. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: This doesn't take care of the case if password / keys to connect to server is changed.

Answer (score 13):

This is the simplest command that satisfies the question (without need for nmap or nc):

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no host.foo.com 2>&1 | grep "Permission denied"
```

Explanation:  attempt to connect with the usual auth methods disabled and grep STDERR for "Permission denied".   Returns exit status 0 if the host is serving SSH, regardless of credentials, and does not hang waiting for password input.

Comment: I wonder why isn't this upvoted, because this is the most straightforward solution. The only thing I would add is a couple of options: `-o BatchMode=yes` to avoid waiting for keyboard input in any case (for example, if host identity has changed) , and `-o ConnectTimeout=5` to control timings. I would also prefer adding `-q` to grep command to keep it silent.

Comment: So the final command for me is: `ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o ChallengeResponseAuthentication=no -p 12345 127.0.0.1 2>&1 | fgrep -q "Permission denied"; echo $?`

Comment: Even better answer from @kvantour 


`ssh-keyscan hostname >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 9):

Netcat should also do the job.

```
nc -z host 22
```

-z specifies that no data be sent and to only scan for running daemons

The output will look something like this:

```
Connection to localhost 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

So if you want to handle this a little more programmatically you could just throw the output to /dev/null and then check that the $? is equal to 0 to verify that the connection is available.

Comment: unfortunately , I do not have nmap and nc in local machine . I am not a root user , so I cannot use them. I have netstate closest to these tools. Any way to achieve the result from netstat ??? 

I totally agree to answer provided, but looking for alternat way.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are checking if some process is listening on the remote machine on the SSH port 22.

But that process might not be an `sshd` daemon (some sysadmins are starting other daemons on that port, e.g. some HTTPS service...).

Or the remote `sshd` daemon has been configured with a non-POSIX shell. For example, as a GCC contributor, I am using `ssh` thru `svn` to `gcc.gnu.org` but I [cannot](https://www.sourceware.org/sourceware/accountinfo.html) run a shell command there...

So I believe you should really try the `ssh` command. If the remote machine is POSIX and you expect to have some Posix shell runnable thru `ssh`, try `ssh remotehost /bin/true` (or perhaps `ssh remotehost 'echo $$'`, with the hope that `echo` would be a remote shell builtin)

Also, an `ssh` command could temporarily fail (e.g. because the remote host has too many processes running under your user, so the `fork` inside `sshd` would fail)

If you want that inside some program, consider using some library like [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/).

BTW, you can configure your *local* `.ssh/config` to never ask any password (or pass with `-F` some specific configuration file ensuring that no password is asked), or (as commented by [CodeGnome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301972/codegnome)), use `ssh -o BatchMode=yes` to disable password prompts.

Comment: ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 <remote-IP> /bin/true

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This command is taking me to password prompt and getting my script to stuck!!

Comment: only in case remote host is reachable over SSH

Comment: Use `-o BatchMode=yes` to disable password prompts.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166507/8344060) from SlackFlag, which attempts an actual login by disallowing any authentication method, you could use `ssh-keyscan`. This essentially does all SSH validations, except an actual login.
It is designed to do different tasks, but is an excellent tool for the problem at hand:

```
$ ssh-keyscan hostname >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Additionally, you can add the `-T n` to have a timeout after `n` seconds.

Comment: This is the simplest SSH based approach (SSH based approaches should be preferred over other approaches)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check continuously in a script whether a node is reachable, e.g. after a reboot, use this loop:

```
until [ $(ssh-keyscan $node >/dev/null 2>&1)$? -eq 0 ]; do
    sleep 10
    # (...)
done
```

`ssh-keyscan` returns 0 when it successfully connects to a node. The loop keeps executing the given set of commands until the exit code of the `ssh-keyscan` command is equal to 0.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `nmap`:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV 172.26.192.0/24 > sshservers
```

Comment: nmap -p 22 --open -sV 172.26.192.0/24
nmap: unrecognized option `--open'
Nmap 3.70 Usage: nmap [Scan Type(s)] [Options] <host or net list>
Some Common Scan Types ('*' options require root privileges)

Comment: I tried on my FC machine with non root-user, my nmap version is 5.21.

Comment: Nmap 3.70? That's [ancient](http://seclists.org/nmap-announce/2004/10), you should really consider updating.

Comment: unfortunately , I do not have nmap and nc in ONE OF MY local machine . I am not a root user , so I cannot use them. I have netstate closest to these tools. Any way to achieve the result from netstat ???

Answer (score -1):

### Grep Output from Nmap

If you need an exit status, grep the results from nmap and use the exit status from grep. For example:

```
$ nmap -sT -Pn -p 22 host.example.com | egrep 'open\s+ssh'
22/tcp open  ssh
```

In this example, the exit status will be from grep, not nmap. Grep will return `0` if the port is open, and `1` if it isn't. You can use the results directly, or branch off of `$?`. For example:

```
nmap -sT -Pn -p 22 host.example.com | egrep -q 'open\s+ssh'
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo 'Not reachable. Exiting ...' > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: unfortunately , I do not have nmap and nc in local machine . I am not a root user , so I cannot use them. I have netstate closest to these tools. Any way to achieve the result from netstat ???